# Would this memoization be faster than just creating the DbProviderFactory every time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, memoization, dbproviderfactories

Would this memoization be faster than just creating the DbProviderFactory every time?

I don't know if the thread locks would be slower than just creating the DbProviderFactory every time.

```
public abstract class Connections {
    private class Memoization 
        : ConcurrentDictionary<string, Tuple<string, DbProviderFactory>> { }

    static Memoization _connectionInfo = new Memoization();

    static DbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionStringSettingsName) {
        var tmp = _connectionInfo.GetOrAdd(connectionStringSettingsName, csn => {
            var config = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[csn];
            var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(config.ProviderName);
            var connectionString = config.ConnectionString;
            return Tuple.Create(connectionString, factory);
        });
        var conn = tmp.Item2.CreateConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = tmp.Item1;
        return conn;
    }
}
```

**Update**

`Memoization` is just a `ConcurrentDictionary<string,Tuple<string,DbProviderFactory>>`.

Comment: How many different storages that requre different provider factory do you use?

Comment: We have several connection strings, we want to be able to test different storage providers for various parts of the system, they are custom.